# Autocomplete off works abnormally when validating field

Tags: javascript, email-validation, autofill

The confirm email validation clears the field value when i use `autocomplete="off"` otherwise works fine. This happens when i land on this page to edit the form from any other page. If i try to type new email address in the confirm email field, the code works fine. The autofill data is the browser cached data.

This is my code:

**Javascript**

```
function validateEmails(){
if( document.getElementById('email').value != document.getElementById('confemail').value) {
    document.getElementById('confemail').setCustomValidity('Confirm Email ID and Email ID do not match');
  } else {
      document.getElementById('confemail').setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

document.getElementById('confemail').onkeyup = validateEmails;
```

### HMTL

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <label class="control-label" for="confirmemail">Confirm
        Email address<span id="star"> *</span>
    </label>

    <form:input path="confirmemail" maxlength="50"
        class="form-control input-sm" type="email" id="confemail"
        placeholder="Please enter your Email Id" onfocus='this.autocomplete=\"off\";'/>

    <form:errors path="confirmemail" element="div" id="confirmemail"
        cssClass="alert alert-error" />
</div>
```

Comment: if the problem occurs when you use autopopulate, don't you think you should show the autopopulate code?

Comment: if he's talking about the browser's autopopulate functionality, there wouldn't be any code for him to show? Please clarify @OP

Comment: I am not using any autopopulate code, i am only using the browser autopopulate data. If i simply type a new email id, everything works fine.